# Detect that 2 string are same but in different order

Tags: python, string-matching

My goal is to detect that 2 string are same but in different order.

```
Example
"hello world my name is foobar" is the same as "my name is foobar world hello"
```

What i already tried is splitting both string into list and compare it within loop.

```
text = "hello world my name is foobar"
textSplit = text.split()

pattern = "foobar is my name world hello"
pattern = pattern.split()

count = 0
for substring in pattern:
    if substring in textSplit:
        count += 1

if (count == len(pattern)):
    print ("same string detected")
```

It return what i intended, but is this actually correct and efficient way? Maybe there is another approach. Any suggestion of journal about that topic would be really nice.

Edit 1: Duplicate words are important

```
text = "fish the fish the fish fish fish"
pattern = "the fish"
```

It must return false

Comment: What about where words are repeated? are "the fish" and "fish the fish the fish fish fish" the same?

Comment: `sorted(text) == sorted(pattern)` maybe? It is not very efficient but it is fairly easy to implement.

Comment: If dups are not important, `len(set(text).difference(pattern)) == 0`

Comment: @OzgurVatansever: What's not efficient about `sorted`? `O(n.log(n))` is almost always good enough, and close to `O(n)`. The problem with your suggestion is that `'abc'` and `'cba'` are considered equal.

Comment: JonClements I missed that case. Thank you. Will update code and question soon. 
OzgurVatansever Thanks for suggestion
Vinny Dups are important

Comment: @EricDuminil adding the `==` check which is `0(n)`, entire complexity would be `0(n^2.log(n))`

Comment: @OzgurVatansever: `Adding`, not `Multiplicating`. `O(n + n.log(n))` is still `O(n.log(n))`

Comment: @EricDuminil you are right. I think sorting the splitted sentence would fix the other problem as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to check that 2 sentences have the same words (with the same number of occurences), you could split the sentences in words and sort them:

```
>>> sorted("hello world my name is foobar".split())
['foobar', 'hello', 'is', 'my', 'name', 'world']
>>> sorted("my name is foobar world hello".split())
['foobar', 'hello', 'is', 'my', 'name', 'world']
```

You could define the check in a function:

```
def have_same_words(sentence1, sentence2):
    return sorted(sentence1.split()) == sorted(sentence2.split())

print(have_same_words("hello world my name is foobar", "my name is foobar world hello"))
# True

print(have_same_words("hello world my name is foobar", "my name is foobar world hello"))
# True

print(have_same_words("hello", "hello hello"))
# False

print(have_same_words("hello", "holle"))
# False
```

If case isn't important, you could compare lowercase sentences:

```
def have_same_words(sentence1, sentence2):
    return sorted(sentence1.lower().split()) == sorted(sentence2.lower().split())

print(have_same_words("Hello world", "World hello"))
# True
```

Note: you could also use `collections.Counter` instead of `sorted`. The complexity would be `O(n)` instead of `O(n.log(n))`, which isn't a big difference anyway. `import collections` might take a longer time than sorting the strings:

```
from collections import Counter

def have_same_words(sentence1, sentence2):
    return Counter(sentence1.lower().split()) == Counter(sentence2.lower().split())

print(have_same_words("Hello world", "World hello"))
# True

print(have_same_words("hello world my name is foobar", "my name is foobar world hello"))
# True

print(have_same_words("hello", "hello hello"))
# False

print(have_same_words("hello", "holle"))
# False
```

Comment: Thank you. It works as intended. 
Can you please summarize or link me what complexity, worst case, and why/how that complexity is defined as O(n). It would be really helpful.

Comment: Sorting is `O(n.log(n)`, counting is `O(n)`. There's not much more to say. Except: Given the size of the sentences, we shouldn't care about complexity.

Comment: Looks like i need to start figure out what are those symbol haha.

Answer (score 3):

I think with your implementation then extra words in the text get ignored (maybe this was intended?).

Ie if `text = "a b"` and `pattern = "a"` then yours prints `"same string detected"`

The way I'd do it:
Comparison where order doesn't matter makes me think of [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html).
So a solution with sets would be:

```
same = set(text.split()) == set(pattern.split())
```

Edit:
Taking into account the repeated words edit to the question:

```
from collections import Counter
split_text = text.split()
split_pattern = pattern.split()
same = (Counter(split_text) == Counter(split_pattern))
```

Comment: Your solution considers that `"hello"` and `"hello hello"` are equal. It's not clear if it's the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a list from each string and calculate a a string intersection between them; if it is as same length as the first on so it's ok they are the same.

```
text = "hello world my name is foobar"
pattern = "foobar is my name world hello"
text = text.split(" ")
pattern = pattern.split(" ")
result = True
if len(text) != len(pattern):
    result = false
else:
    l = list(set(text) & set(pattern))
    if len(l)!=len(text):
        result = False
if result == True:
    print ("same string detected")
else:
    print ("Not the same string")
```

Comment: You need to be wary of your length check there... `if len(l) != len(text)` - since `l` has duplicates removed then where `text` has duplicated words - this check isn't going to be reliable...

Comment: `set(text)` and `set(pattern)`  removes duplicates

Answer (score 0):

you can also make a new string str12 from the strings you want to compare. Then compare the lenght of str12 with 2 * (str12 without duplicate)

```
str1 = "hello world my name is foobar"
str2 = "my name is foobar world hello"


str12 = (str1 + " " +str2).split(" ")

str12_remove_duplicate = list(set(str12))

if len(str12) == 2 * len(str12_remove_duplicate):
    print("String '%s' and '%s' are SAME but different order" % (str1, str2))
else: 
    print("String '%s' and '%s' are NOT SAME" % (str1, str2))
```